# How to create async function in typescript to return coordinates of specific location

Tags: typescript, async-await, geometry, fetch, coordinates

[I need to return coordinates of location as function output and those coordinates already assined inside fetch as coordinates.lat and coordinates.lng](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvK6M.png)

[its currently returning coordinates lat : 0, lng: 0 as I declared at begging and I need change that coordinates into new coordinates after fetch data]

Comment: hey there, welcome to stack overflow. please have a look at [ask], specifically the part about not posting images of your code, as well as the info the [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.then()`, which runs asynchronously once the previous code has completed, in a non-blocking way. So when you have

```js
somethingThatTakesAWhile().then(()=>{console.log("A"})
console.log("B");
```

you'll end up with the output

```
B
A
```

Mark your function as asynchronous, use the `await` keyword instead of the `then` syntax and you should have a nice readable function that does what you want it to do.

```js
async function getLatLng(location) {
  let response = await fetch(...);
  let data = await response.json();
  let coordinates = {lat: data..., lng: data...}
  return coordinates;
}
```

Read up on [how promises / asynchronous code works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await).